# Is $i$ equal to $\sqrt{-1}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Some of my math teachers said that $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is the wrong definition for $i$ and that the correct definition is $i^2=-1$. If the second definition if true, then does it mean $\sqrt{-1}= ±i$? Which of the two definitions is true?

Comment: $i^2=-1$ is not defining anything. Since, if you have a number that satisfies it its opposite also satisfies it.

Comment: $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is actually more proper. You are picking **precisely one** new element required to satisfy that $(\sqrt{-1})^2=-1$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/887724/refining-my-knowledge-of-the-imaginary-number

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13801/321264

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a formal algebraic perspective, $\Bbb{C}$ is the field $\Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ which is [the field you get by adjoining](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) to $\Bbb{R}$ the roots of $x^2 + 1$ and all the linear combinations of the form $a+ib$, where $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$. You really need to add just one of them (we call it $i$), because the other is just $0 + i(-1)$. Notice that it doesn't matter which we pick as $i$: if I pick one and you picked the other, we would never notice we made different choices.

Infact, the [Galois group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_group) (automorphisms preserving the original field, thus fixing $\Bbb{R}$ in this case) of $\Bbb{C}$ has exactly two automorphisms: the identity, sending $i$ to itself, and the conjugation, sending $i$ to its opposite. By definition, automorphisms preserve structure, thus confirming the choice of $i$ doesn't really matter.

Comment: Id est, from your reasoning follows that $\sqrt{-1}=\{i,-i\}$. Am I right?

Comment: If by $\sqrt{a}$ we mean the roots of the equation $x^2 - a = 0$, yes. Yet it doesn't make sense to _define_ $i$ that way because as far as $\Bbb{R}$ is concerned, that equation doesn't have roots.

Comment: Surely, usually we aren't that pedantic and such a definition meets the right intuition, but if we want to answer questions such as this one, we have to.

Comment: But by your way we get something not good. For $\sqrt{2i}=\{1+i,-1-i\}$ you don't remember any another definition and for $\sqrt{-1}$ you make it. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding your point. Are you saying we are _defining_ it for $i$ and _using_ it for $2i$, so that the same symbol means two different things?

Comment: I say about $\sqrt{-1}$ only. What is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62642/discussion-between-mattecapu-and-michael-rozenberg).

Comment: Yet, it has been a fresh answer after years!

Answer (score 4):

The square root symbol does not make sense when applied to a negative number.  Granted, people often write it that way for convenience.  $i$ is defined by the equation $i^2=-1$.  Yes, if there is a field containing a root of $x^2+1$ then if $i$ is such a root so is $-i$. When we define a field such as $\mathbb C$ we are implicitly choosing a root of $x^2+1$.

Comment: The $\sqrt.$ here is different from the normal $\sqrt. :\Bbb R^{\ge0}\rightarrow\Bbb R^{\ge0}$. We're defining a 'new version' with the same symbol for convenience as it extends the old one.

Comment: @Shuri2060  You can't define $i$ and $\sqrt x$ in the one line.  That is, you can't define $i$ in terms of $\sqrt x$ and simultaneously define $\sqrt x$ in terms of $i$.

Comment: It depends, but I think $\sqrt.$ is usually first extended so that its domain is $\Bbb R$ with the requirements that it remains a bijection. Then $i$ is a 'shorthand' for $\sqrt{-1}$ much like $2$ is a shorthand for $S(1)$.

Comment: @Shuri2060  Well, I'd define that extension by saying that $x<0\implies \sqrt x=\sqrt {|x| } \, i$. With $i$ defined as one of the roots of $x^2+1$ over $\mathbb R$.   How would you define it? Is there some nice axiomatic way to do it?  Anyway, I have to imagine that the OP means to start with $i$ and then extend the definition of $\sqrt x$, no?

Comment: I see - in which case I think your way of defining it would probably be best. But perhaps there is some nice axiomatic way of doing it - I'll think about it.

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt{\cdot}$ is seen in most cases as a function in $[0,\infty)$, so it have a unique value associated to each non-negative real. In this tradition we generally define $i:=\sqrt{-1}$, that can be thought informally as a kind of extension to the classical square root function.

Indeed we can extend the definition of the square root to any complex number, setting it as the principal value of $\sqrt z:=e^{1/2\ln z}$ with the same result.

However is true that $(-i)^2=-1$.

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{-1}$ is denoted as $i$ and $i$ is a solution of the algebraic equation $x^2+1=0$. That is why $i^2=-1$.

One could define $i=-\sqrt{-1}$ and using this notation he could built the Complex analysis. That is up to him.