# Open covering for rationals in [0, 1].

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness

The set of all rational numbers in the closed interval $[0,1]$ is not closed, and therefore not compact. Hence, there must exist an open covering for this set that has no finite sub-covering. Explicitly construct such an open covering.
My attempt at an answer is as follows. The rationals in the closed unit interval are countably infinite. So if we enumerate them, center the $i^{th}$ rational in an open segment of width $1/2^{i+1}$. This forms an open covering of all the rationals in the closed unit interval. Then any finite sub covering formed using this open covering must have length strictly less than 1, and must therefore miss some rationals. I feel uncomfortable with this proof. But am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: What have you tried?  What are your thoughts?  We generally don't just answer questions without some effort on your part

Comment: This was answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2034380/proof-mathbb-q-cap-0-1-is-not-compact-with-the-definition

Comment: It does! But is my answer wrong? Why do they need to use intervals whose widths are irrational?

Comment: Let me suggest that, in order to avoid close votes, you edit your question to include, in the text of your question, those attempts that you have explained in the comments.

Comment: That way you can specifically ask, in the text of your question, whether your proof attempt is correct or incorrect, and (possibly) avoid your question being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: That would work. Proving that it does would, I think, be a bit tedious. (My last, deleted, comment was off...)

Comment: Your suggestion was taken into account when I posted the question again. I also followed Alan, and Lee’s suggestion and posted the question with my possibly flawed answer.

Comment: I think you were right David. If I start with an interval of width 1 around the first rational, I am doomed!

Comment: $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$ can be covered by a countably infinite family $F$ of open intervals such that $\sum_{f\in F}|f| <1.$ But you are $correct$ in asserting that if $G$ is a $finite$ family of open intervals and $\cup G\supset \Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$ then  $\sum_{g\in G}|g|\ge 1.$ But you should  prove it.

Comment: Alan, I checked the proofs  "Proof: Q∩[0,1] is not compact (with the definition)", (Apologies not sure how to replicate what you did and attach the link). They are interesting but none appear to be the proof that I am attempting to give-which elaborates DAniel Wainfleet's sketch.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $\{{r_1},{r_2},\cdots \}$ is a countably infinite enumeration of the rational numbers in ${\bf Q}\cap [0,1].$ Fix ${\epsilon}\in (0,1)$, and define $${I_j}=\bigg({{r_i}-{\frac{\epsilon}{2^{(i+1)}}}},{{r_i}+{\frac{\epsilon}{2^{(i+1)}}\bigg)}}.$$ Then the length of $I_j$ is ${\epsilon}/2^i.$ And all the rationals in ${\bf Q}\cap [0,1]$ must then be contained in a countable union of open intervals  whose measure is  $\le\epsilon<1.$ (We are summing a geometric series with common ratio $1/2$ starting at the index $1$, the sum being multiplied by a constant factor of $\epsilon$). Thus this forms an open covering of ${\bf Q}\cap [0,1].$ If ${\bf Q}\cap [0,1]$ were compact, it would have a finite sub-covering. We can label this finite sub-covering  $$\{I_{s_1},\cdots, {I_{s_m}}\},$$ these being open intervals centered at rationals ${r_{s_1}},\cdots ,{r_{s_m}}.$ We now observe that the measure of this subcovering cannot exceed $\epsilon.$ On the other hand as Mr. Wainfleet (Dr. Wainfleet?) observes, as this finite subcovering by open intervals must contain $0$ and $1$, it must have length at least $1$, as the rationals are dense in $[0,1]$, which is a contradiction. This proof was inspired by Mr. Wainfleet's sketch and so he deserves my sincere thanks. It seems to be the case that even the infinite open covering has length less than 1 in this particular choice of an open cover-so this choice of $\epsilon$ seems to make the finiteness of the covering less significant than it might seem-not surprising-after all the rationals have measure $0$ even in $\bf R$.

Comment: This answer seem to be different from the other answers to this question because it does not require  on the widths of the open intervals containing the rationals to have irrational length. Although I use "measure" I could just use the word "length" for length of an interval.

Comment: Although I stated that in this case the finiteness of the covering "seems" to be less significant, it is is the crux of what makes the argument work.

Comment: The same argument can generalized to prove that a dense countably infinite set of an arbitrary compact subset (ay a finite union of closed and bounded intervals) of ${\bf R}$ has an open covering which does not have a finite sub-covering

Comment: DanielWainfleet your sketch was very useful. I realized that centering the $i^{th}$ rational  in an open segment of width ${\epsilon}/2^{i}$ for $0<{\epsilon} < 1$ ensures that we will never cover the entire closed unit interval with a *finite* sub-cover. If we are allowed to use an infinite number of such open segments, we can cover any countably infinite subset of ${\bf R}$