# If the answer is "no" then "yes" and vice versa type of paradoxes. What are they?

Tags: logic, paradoxes

I'm a complete layman, so my technical terms might be misleading. Sorry for the many small questions, it's just that I don't know how to formulate my question right.

**What is the deal with paradoxes like the liar's/Epimenides' paradox, the Barber's and Russell's paradox, Turing's proof for the Halting problem etc, in which "if the answer is *no*, then *yes*, and if *yes* then *no*."?**

Why are they so meaningful and baffling? How are they revolutionizing? How can they be used as proofs or refutations for theories? Isn't that a problem in which the answer affects the answer itself? And a bit further, do they imply something non-dual, even something like a superposition?

For all I know they just seem to me like a catchy riddle. Such as: *"answer yes or no, will your next answer be 'no'?"*

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but those paradoxes you mentioned are paradoxes of self-reference. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_paradoxes#Self-reference

Comment: Essentially, Russell's paradox shows that we should take care in how we define sets (which a basic building block of mathematics). Naively, a set can be defined as the collection of all objects which satisfy some property, but this doesn't always give well defined objects: the set $R$ of all sets not contained in themselves is neither in or outside $R$ itself, which is in contradiction with the law of excluded middle. It is not *baffling* in and of itself, but it tells us that we must look for a more refined way to define sets.

Comment: The "common pattern" to Russell's Paradox and Turing's Halting problem is the proof method : proof by contradiction. We assume that a certain "fact" $F$ holds and we derive a contradiction; thus, we conclude that the said "fact" does not hold, i.e. we conclude with $\lnot F$. In the first case is the "naive" assumption that for any "condition" expressible in the language of set theory, a set exists of all and only those objects satisfying the condition. In Turing's case the "fact" is the assumption that the so-called Halting problem can be "addressed" by a "computational" procedure.

Comment: I wrote about the significance of Russell's paradox here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086645/is-russells-paradox-really-about-sets-as-such/1086676#1086676

Answer (score 1):

The *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy* is a rich (but free!) source of information about the paradoxes. You could usefully start, for example, with the entry on [Self-reference](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/).

Comment: Great thanks, I'll get a clearer picture from it.